# changing django admin panel interface

Tags: django, django-templates

[here is the Django default admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc1gA.png)

I want to keep the functionality (like accessing users table and buttons) but change the interface.
I don't want to write Django and It is also hard and needs much time to style this panel again.
I want exactly the default admin panel but with an attractive style and appearance.
I saw Django admin dashboard templates but it did not have the functionality, for example a button that when you click you can see users table and you can add or edit user.
Is there any quick way (like templates or a stylesheet) to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your `admin-panel` in admin.py like you can change the layout and everything . But, you have to code for them.
**Template** isn't use for customizing `admin-panel`

Comment: you may ask the exact thing you want to customize.